# Passing class name as a parameter

Tags: java, javafx

I have following function

```
public void loadWindowAndSendDataTest(String path, String appName, ConnectionData connectionData) {
    try {
        Stage subWindow = new Stage();
        subWindow.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent parent = loader.load(getClass().getResource(path).openStream());
        ExitController exitController = (ExitController) loader.getController();
        exitController.getConnectionData(connectionData);

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

        subWindow.setScene(scene);
        subWindow.setTitle(appName);
        subWindow.show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And what I'd like to achive is to have more general function where I can pass class name (in this case ExitController), so it would like something like this:

```
public void loadWindowAndSendDataTest(String path, String appName, ConnectionData connectionData, String className) {
    try {
        Stage subWindow = new Stage();
        subWindow.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent parent = loader.load(getClass().getResource(path).openStream());
        /* do sth with className to obtain UsedClassController class */
        UsedClassController usedClassController = (UsedClassController) loader.getController();
        usedClassControler.getConnectionData(connectionData);

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

        subWindow.setScene(scene);
        subWindow.setTitle(appName);
        subWindow.show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The assumption is that the class I'm passing to this function have `getConnectionData()` fuction implemented. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: well you could write an interface which has the method `getConnectionData()` and you can later on check if the class behind the classname is of that interface and then you can call it safely

Comment: Ok I see but how can I pass class name as a parameter and then get this class inside a function to do f.e. casting?

Comment: to get the class object: if you got a Class(say String), you can use `Class<T> String.class`; if you got an object(say obj), you can use `Class<T> obj.getClass()`..... to get the name you can use the function `Class.getName()` on your class object, then it's a String, to convert it to a class again, you can use `Class.forName(String)`

Comment: Note that you don't actually need an explicit cast at all, since [`getController()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController--) is a generic method, and in Java 8 and later the compiler will infer the generic type. So you can do `ExitController exitController = loader.getController();`. Of course, a cast still occurs at runtime, and can fail if the controller is the wrong type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're assuming the controller class has the `getConnectionData(ConnectionData)` method implemented, you could just use reflection to invoke that method:

```
public void loadWindowAndSendDataTest(String path, String appName, ConnectionData connectionData) {
    try {
        Stage subWindow = new Stage();
        subWindow.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent parent = loader.load(getClass().getResource(path).openStream());
        Object controller = loader.getController();
        Method getConnectionDataMethod = 
            controller.getClass().getMethod("getConnectionData", ConnectionData.class);
        getConnectionDataMethod.invoke(controller, connectionData);

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

        subWindow.setScene(scene);
        subWindow.setTitle(appName);
        subWindow.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This isn't a particularly robust or elegant approach. Perhaps better is to define an interface with the `getConnectionData` method:

```
public interface ConnectionDataProvider {

    public void getConnectionData(ConnectionData data) ;

}
```

and to have your controllers implement that method:

```
public class ExitController implements ConnectionDataProvider {

    public void getConnectionData(ConnectionData data) {
        // ...
    }

    // existing code ...
}
```

Then you can just assume the controller is from a class implementing that method:

```
public void loadWindowAndSendDataTest(String path, String appName, ConnectionData connectionData) {
    try {
        Stage subWindow = new Stage();
        subWindow.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent parent = loader.load(getClass().getResource(path).openStream());
        ConnectionDataProvider controller = loader.getController();
        controller.getConnectionData(connectionData);

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

        subWindow.setScene(scene);
        subWindow.setTitle(appName);
        subWindow.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that neither of these approaches requires you to pass in the type (class) of the controller. If you really needed that for some reason, you could do the following (using the interface approach):

```
public <T extends ConnectionDataProvider> void loadWindowAndSendDataTest(
        String path, String appName, 
        ConnectionData connectionData, Class<T> controllerType) {

    try {
        Stage subWindow = new Stage();
        subWindow.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent parent = loader.load(getClass().getResource(path).openStream());
        T controller = loader.getController();

        // if you wanted to cast explicitly here, you could do:
        // T controller = controllerType.cast(loader.getController());

        controller.getConnectionData(connectionData);

        // do something with controllerType if you need....

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

        subWindow.setScene(scene);
        subWindow.setTitle(appName);
        subWindow.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and then you would invoke this with

```
loadWindowAndSendDataTest("/path/to/fxml", "Application Name", 
    connectionData, ExitController.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create an interface with method `getConnectionData()`, implement this interface in your  `UsedClassController` class.

To get name of the class try to use `getSimpleName()` from class object. Example for BigDecimal:

```
 BigDecimal.class.getSimpleName();
```

will return `BigDecimal`.
If you want to get the name with package, you can use `getCanonicalName()`

Comment: `String Class.getSimpleName()` wouldn't allow him to convert it back, since it lacks the package, i suggest to use `String Class.getName()`